# How can I do an inline sort?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to take a list, re-order it and replace the original.

Is there a better way to do this? Currently I am re-assigning it and it feels silly...

Here is my code:

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
viewModel.Children = viewModel.Children.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) method.

```
viewModel.Children.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a.Name, b.Name));
```

Comment: great, my only word of advice, don't .ToList().Sort as it wont sort the property, i had to modify my original model to use a list instead.

Comment: @shenkum, you are correct, please ignore my previous comment.

Comment: The problem with this is that Sort is a method of List, but this method doesn't exist on other collections like ObservableCollection, and that is where it is really needed because if you are trying to sort inline, it's probably because you don't want the UI to do a full refresh.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) method instead of.

> Sorts the elements in the entire `List<T>` using the specified
>   `System.Comparison<T>`.

```
viewModel.Children.Sort((a, b) => String.Compare(a.Name, b.Name))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `lambda expressions`:

```
viewModel.Children.Sort((a, b) => String.Compare(a.Name, b.Name))
```

For IList it won't work:

```
viewModel.Children = viewModel.Children.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: `(a) => String.Compare(a.Name)` <-- not sure that will even compile.